# Give atribute values with a constructor that does not define them (Matrix (int, int))

Tags: c++, class, constructor, declaration

If if have a constructor just with this: `Matrix(int, int);`

How can I give the class's attributes a value? For example:

```
Matrix::Matrix(int, int)
{
    columns= //(and here what? If there is no reference I do not know what to assign it for)

}
```

I know it is easier to just write Matrix(int i, int j), but what if there are only the "int"s?

Comment: *If if have a constructor just with this: Matrix(int, int)* -- Why are you trying to make things harder than they should?  What's wrong with `Matrix(int i, int j)`?

Comment: Here is a good example of a matrix class with most of the bells and whistles: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
Matrix(int, int);
```

is just a constructor declaration. There is no need to specify names of the parameters because they are not used in the declaration. It is enough to specify the types of the parameters.

But in the constructor definition you need to specify names of the parameters. For example

```
Matrix::Matrix(int rows, int cols)
{
    //...
}
```

You can use these names of the parameters in expressions for example to initialize data members of the class.